# C++ Linked List Push_back ERROR

Tags: c++, list

Getting error

```
 tryout.cpp:29: error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<char, std::allocator<char> >::push_back(std::string&)'/opt/csw/gcc4/lib/gcc/sparc-sunsolaris2.8/4.0.2/../../../../include/c++/4.0.2/bits/stl_list.h:773: note: candidates are: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = char, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

trying to push a .text file using argument into list however it wont push
code is below

```
 int main (int argc, char* argv[])
 {


    string vowels;
    list<string> myList;

    ifstream infile(argv[1]); 

    //open the file

    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {

       while (infile.get(vowels))) {        
       myList.push_back(vowels));

    infile.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Clear the mess first.

Comment: Besides, your test case is missing some headers and some std:: (due to laziness), the actual error is: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(std::string&)’

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char vowels;
    list<char> myList;
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        while (infile.get(vowels)) myList.push_back(vowels);
        infile.close();
    }
    return 0;        
}
```